# Как работают «знаки»?

Tags: поддержка, faq, знаки

- Что представляют собой *знаки*?
- Как участники получают *знаки*?
- Как участники могут получить *знак по метке*?
- Что может привести к потере/отзыву/отмене присвоенного знака?
- Как предложить новый знак?

> Более подробно см. в [«Что такое знаки?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges) и в [списке знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) в [справочном-центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

---

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 12):

### Что представляют собой *знаки*?

Знаки присуждаются участникам в качестве признания их вклада в развитие сообщества. Существует множество различных способов участия в жизни сообщества – следовательно, существует множество различных знаков.

Есть три ранга знаков:

- **Бронзовые знаки** (их достаточно легко получить); часто они присваиваются за то, что участник научился работать с тем или иным функционалом системы.
- **Серебряные знаки** (получить труднее): их можно заслужить, опубликовав особенно ценные и содержательные вопросы или ответы, а также за модерацию и улучшение содержимого сайта.
- **Золотые знаки** (получить труднее всего): как правило, их дают за исключительную вовлеченность и особые заслуги перед сообществом.

Все знаки, полученные участником, отображаются в его профиле. Кроме того, в карточке каждого участника указывается число полученных знаков, распределенных по рангам.

Большинство знаков, которые может получить участник, не влияют на функциональность сайта: это просто знаки достижений и повод для гордости (способности и таланты участников отражены не в полученных ими знаках, а в заслуженной ими [репутации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3663)).

### Как участники получают *знаки*?

- *См. также: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/143601)*

Участники получают знаки используя сайт. На [странице знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges) подробно описано, что конкретно необходимо сделать, чтобы получить каждый из знаков. Если участник соответствует критериям того или иного знака, автоматизированный фоновый процесс добавит знак в его учетную запись.

Некоторые знаки можно получить более одного раза. В этом случае, имя участника появляется на странице этого знака столько раз, сколько раз был получен знак. В перечне знаков на странице учётной записи участника, напротив знака, полученного более одного раза, также будет стоять множитель, соответствующий числу награждений.

В некоторых случаях число полученных знаков может обновляться с некоторой задержкой – до следующего пересчета знаков, который производится системой с определенной периодичностью.

### Как участники могут получить *знак по метке*?

Знаки по метке присуждаются, когда у участника накапливается установленное количество баллов репутации по вопросам с меткой. Существует три уровня: чтобы получить «бронзу», необходимо набрать 100 баллов, «серебро» – 400 баллов, «золото» – 1000 баллов. Учитываются только те ответы, которые *не* являются общими.

Например, если участник получил 400 баллов за ответы в вопросах с меткой «java», он получит серебряный знак «java». Заработая еще 600 баллов, участник получит золотой знак!

Участник может [наблюдать за своим прогрессом](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/2365) используя Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Дополнительно см. [Specialist Badge Implemented](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/specialist-badge-implemented/).

### Что может привести к потере/отзыву/отмене полученного знака?

«Обычные» знаки, полученные честным способом, не аннулируются. Что считать честным способом, а что обманом, определяется разработчиками в каждом конкретном случае индивидуально. Основные принципы следующие:

- Использование многочисленных учетных записей, повышающих рейтинг основной учетной записи участника – для знаков [«Просвещенный»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) или [«Хороший вопрос»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) можно считать обманом.
- Голосование против, а затем отмену своего голоса, чтобы получить знак
  [«Критик»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic) за так – это глупо и некрасиво.

Знаки по метке исчезают сразу после того, как участник перестает соответствовать их критериям, что может произойти в результате удаления сообщений или падения их рейтинга.

«Обычные» знаки, полученные участниками, остаются с ними навсегда. Даже если критерии, в соответствии с которыми были получены знаки изменились (сообщения были удалены, репутация участника уменьшилась и т. п.), участники сохранят свои знаки. Если участник заслужил еще один знак, совпадающий с уже имеющимся (например, в результате публикации еще одного вопроса/ответа), первый знак не пропадет – знаки будут  [суммироваться](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187740).

### Как предложить новый знак?

Воспользуйтесь [поиском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search) (а также на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=badge-request)), чтобы убедиться, что этот знак не был предложен до вас, а затем опубликуйте свое предложение как новый вопрос с меткой [запрос-знака](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Помните, что знаки представляют собой награду: просьба об учреждении нового знака *исключительно* ради того, чтобы просто создать новый знак, скорее всего, будет отклонена. Поэтому убедитесь, что ваше предложение имеет под собой основания – подробно объясните, как будет «работать» знак, какую положительную модель поведения будет стимулировать и почему эта модель *не* подкрепляется другими существующими знаками.

Comment: `Воспользуйтесь поиском, чтобы убедиться` - думаю, стоит искать по Meta SE.

Comment: а знаки только общие или на сайтах могут быть свои специальные?

Comment: @Grundy Общие для всех сайтов сети.

Comment: @Grundy, на эту тему было минимум 2 вопроса, но на них так и не ответили...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, то есть не получится ввести знак _Телепат RU.SO_? :-) или там _Единственный профессионал на этом сайте_?

Comment: @Grundy, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2807/178988

Comment: стоит явно выразить мысль: знаки (особенно бронзовые и не за метки) это прежде всего ненавязчивый инструмент, чтобы показать желаемое (ожидаемое системой) поведение на сайте (то есть если вы что-то сделали и получили знак—это способ выразить программно: правильно сделали, продолжайте в том же духе). Знаки в этом смысле являются расширением [начального тура](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, на странице описания знаков для многих из знаков очень непонятное и скудное описание. К примеру, «Перепись населения» я вообще и близко не понимаю как его получить? Также хотелось бы видеть под каждым знаком сколько раз его можно получить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, как получить знак "Перепись населения"?

Comment: @Bharata, поучаствовать в ежегодном опросе SO.

Comment: @Bharata, ну он же не случайно ежегодным называется. Он проводится раз в год (если не ошибаюсь, неделю или две). Сейчас не найти нигде.