# Как работает репутация?

Tags: поддержка, faq, репутация

Участники сообществ Stack Exchange могут приобретать репутацию.

- Каков механизм формирования репутации?
- Каким образом участники могут приобретать или терять репутацию?

> ### См. также
>
> - [Что такое репутация? Как ее приобрести/потерять?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).
> - [Существуют ли какие-либо ограничения при голосовании?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits-in-stackoverflow)
>     Максимальное количество голосов, которые может выставить пользователь за день; требования к репутации при голосовании
> - [Как я могу проверить свою репутацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3539/)
>     Как получить точный отчет о действиях, сформировавших вашу репутацию.

---

<sub>Перевод «[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 9):

### Что такое репутация?

Ваша репутация – часть вашей виртуальной личности в сообществе, которая в определенной мере отражает степень вашего понимания работы сайта, глубину ваших профессиональных знаний, а также уровень «уважения», которым вы пользуетесь среди коллег. В общем случае, репутация формируется, когда другие участники одобряют публикуемые вами вопросы и ответы.

Согласно имеющейся репутации участника, определяются его привилегии в системе. При увеличении репутации участник получает больший кредит доверия системы, а как результат, доступ к более широкому набору функционала, который недоступен участникам с низкой репутацией.

Рост репутации не просто дает новые возможности, но и накладывает новые обязанности. Порог репутации для получения привилегий на разных сайтах может незначительно различаться; см. [страницу привилегий](/privileges). **Общепринятые пороговые значения репутации для новых сайтов, сайтов в стадии открытой беты и сайтов прошедших аттестацию доступны в [сравнительной таблице репутации](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).**

### Как приобретать или терять репутацию?

Репутация участников растет или уменьшается в зависимости от качества их взаимодействия с системой и другими участниками сообщества. Основной способ изменения репутации – голосование. Если сообщение получает голос «за», репутация ее автора увеличивается; при голосовании «против» репутация уменьшается. Голоса «за» имеют больший вес, чем голоса «против». Публикации, имеющие статус общих, являются исключением из правил формирования репутации: голоса «за» или «против» таких публикаций никак не влияют на репутации их авторов (и всех тех, кто в последствии вносит изменения). Это справедливо и [для принятия ответов](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35928/2-on-accepting-answers-something-is-wrong-with-my-account-on-so/35930#35930) в общих вопросах.

#### Ваша репутация растет, если

- один из ваших вопросов получает голос *за*: **+10**;
- один из ваших ответов получает голос *за*: **+10**;
- один из ваших ответов *принят*: **+15**;
- вы *принимаете* ответ, данный другим участником на один из ваших вопросов: **+2**;
- голос «против» одного из ваших вопросов или ответов удален: **+2**;
- вы [предложили правку, и она была принята](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work): **+2** (суммарно не больше +1000 на одного участника);
- вы удалили свой голос «против» чьего-либо ответа: **+1**;
- ответ, против которого вы проголосовали, был удален: **+1**;
- один из ваших ответов побеждает в конкурсе (в результате выбора автором конкурса): **+сумма вознаграждения**;
- один из ваших ответов побеждает в конкурсе автоматически: **+1/2 суммы вознаграждения** (более подробно см. [FAQ по конкурсам](/a/3619/6));
- вы *связываете учетные записи* двух или более сайтов сети Stack Exchange, и по крайней мере одна из них имеет репутацию 200 и более: **+100** на каждом сайте (присуждается только один раз для каждого сайта).

#### Ваша репутация падает, если

- один из ваших вопросов или ответов получает голос *против*: **−2**;
- сообщение, для которого вы успешно *предложили правку*, было *удалено* (на странице репутации в качестве причины указано "*удален*"): **-2**;
- учетная запись *участника, который последним одобрил предложенную вами правку,* [была удалена](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413) (на странице репутации в качестве причины указано «*Участник был удален*»): **-2**;
- вы голосуете *против* какого–либо ответа: **−1**;
- голос за один из ваших вопросов удален: **−10**;
- голос за один из ваших ответов удален: **−10**;
- один из ваших *принятых* ответов утрачивает статус *«принят»*: **−15**;
- вы *отменяете статус «принят»* относительно ответа другого участника на один из ваших вопросов: **-2**;
- вы начинаете конкурс на вопрос: **−сумма вознаграждения**;
- одно из ваших сообщений получает 6 сигналов тревог [«спам»](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work) или [«оскорбительное сообщение»](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work): **−100**.

#### Дополнительно

- Все участники начинают с репутации в один балл.
- Репутация не может быть ниже одного балла; если действие вызовет падение репутации участника ниже одного балла, его репутация считается равной одному баллу ([источник](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)).
- Вы можете заработать не более +200 баллов на голосах «за» и предлагаемых правках [в день](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). Награды в конкурсах и бонусы за принятые ответы подсчитываются отдельно ([источник](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). Излишек баллов сверх этого ограничения аннулируется и в последующие дни не возмещается.
- Если сообщение получает голос до того, как оно становится общим, то после того как оно станет общим, *удаление* на репутацию не влияет ([источник](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29088/downvote-removed-score-of-downvoted-user-unchanged)).
- Удаление и восстановление сообщения может сказываться на репутации, если за такое сообщение были отданы голоса. Действия, совершенные ранее над удаленными публикациями, прекращают учитываться при пересчете репутации в течение некоторого времени с момента удаления ([источник](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)), за исключением той ситуации, когда такие публикации удовлетворяет следующим критериям (в этом случае баллы продолжают учитываться) ([источник](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)):

  - рейтинг сообщения составляет минимум +3 балла;
  - сообщение пробыло на сайте как минимум 60 дней.
- Принятие собственного ответа на репутацию не влияет.
- [Манипуляции с голосами](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work) в результате [серийного голосования](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) (речь идет о намеренном выставлении высоких баллов репутации, чтобы соответствующие участники превысили дневное ограничение в 200 баллов, с отзывом выставленных баллов на следующий день) на репутацию не повлияют.
- Голосование за комментарии на репутацию не влияет.

#### Если все начинают с одного балла, откуда берется репутация?

На сайтах Stack Exchange есть четыре способа получения первой репутации:

- Если участники приходят с другого сайта сети (где имеют более 200 баллов репутации), они получают 100 баллов репутации.
- Участники дают ответы, которые отмечают принятыми, или сами принимают ответы других участников в своих вопросах (+15 и +2, соответственно).
- Участники вносят улучшающие полезные правки (автор исходного сообщения имеет определяющий голос относительно предлагаемых правок, если они не были на данный момент одобрены или отклонены).
- Во время «беты» привилегия голосования доступна при пороге в один балл репутации.

Comment: Что за действие "Unicorn Parsing HTML w/ RegEx T-Shirt" ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared )? Такой привилегии не знаю.

Comment: @Other предполагаю, что футболка по мотивам [мема StackOverflow о парсинге HTML регулярными выражениями](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2076787).

Comment: @D-side, что-то типа: набрал 200k - получи фирменную футболку? Класс, было бы чудесно купить такую футболку :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я заметил: если изменить свой ответ, которому больше 40 минут, то теряется 2 балла репутации? У меня раз 5 уже такое было и они не отображаются в истории репутации. Возможно я неправильно пока думаю, но баллы у меня теряются и их не видно в истории.

Comment: @Bharata Нет. Правка не уменьшает рейтинг ответа (как и вашу репутацию). -2 получается потому что кто–то поставил минус вашему сообщению. Но! На сайте есть несколько хитрых механизмов, упрощающих модерацию. Например, если вы опубликуете очень короткий ответ (+ еще какие–то параметры), система может сама выставить на него тревогу «сообщение низкого качества». На сколько помню, если внести улучшающую правку в такое сообщение, оно получит минус от системы, а его автор -2 репутации.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, когда мне кто-то ставит минус, то он отображается в истории, а эти -2 там не отображаются. Остаётся выяснить за что. Во всяком случае неотображение в истории - это ошибка системы, которую надо исправить.