# -100 баллов за ответ, где можно узнать за что?

Tags: поддержка

[Создание рубрик программно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659886/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be/660179#660179)

если связанно с ответом:
никаких сообщений в личку не вижу о причинах и задать вопрос не знаю как, что нет так было, ссылки на ресурс где этот двиг произведен? и что за пометка @спам?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/abuse-block

*@В настоящее время ваше сообщение невозможно опубликовать из-за большого количества спама и чрезмерной нагрузки, исходящей из вашей сети. Приносим свои извинения за доставленные неудобства. Посетите Справку для получения дополнительной информации.@*

Если с железом:
+у меня 2 статических ip, которым более 5 лет, ни разу нигде не засвеченых, что за наезды? после разбирательств это сообщение просьба удалить.

++ на роутере режим использования каналов - смешанный, если один занят или нагружен, сообщения идут с другого. Но в настройках этого форума я не видел аналогичную галку как на маил.ру "сессия только с одного ип". Если поднимите логи - то увидите, что коннекты идут с 2х основных ип адресов (на которых кста мои сайты висят, созвучные логину). За несколько лет использования SO в англ.ветке таких проблем не было.

Поясните плз

Comment: к данному вопросу не относится но.....`За несколько лет использования SO в англ.ветке таких проблем не было.` - если вы несколько лет использоуете SO, то знаете правила и все равно в **ответах** опубликовали ссылки на сторонние ресурсы и что, по сути, не является ответом.. Что вы ожидали намеренно нарушая правила ресурса — неизвестно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает репутация?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3663/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: не, ребята, не согласен я с такой оценкой. ответы\комменты ниже прочитал, но я не вижу ничего зазорного в том, чтобы дать (причем заранее говоря, что это не ответ) ссылку на форум разработчика продукта, где я часто бываю и мне по таким вопросам неоднократно безвозмездно помогали (иногда даже просто указывая плагин - а в его коде смотрим что надо, продукт-то открытый). и я не говорил "что тут не ответят", просто WP  на сегодня часто меняется и оптимальный ответ кодом, был бы получен там. короче считаю слишком сильным наказание.

Comment: + что мне теперь, лучше на вопросы не отвечать, с таким подходом? ну ок, буду только задавать.

Comment: @Gu. вместо такого ответа лучше писать комментарий.

Answer (score 12):

Вы запостили *два* ответа к разным вопросам с глубокомысленным содержанием вида "ммм, тут вам лучше помогут *ссылка на сторонний ресурс".

Вот второй: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660180/.

Ответ, суть которого - "тут тебе не ответят, спроси лучше вот на этом форуме" - это спам.

Один просто удалили, второй - через тревогу. Удаление через тревогу спама вызывает временную блокировку IP.

А ответы, состоящие на 80% из посыла в Гугл + ссылки на (свой же?) блог, вроде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659539/, с сокращенными матами в комментариях - это вообще прямой путь к бану.

Comment: ...это же была опечатка , да?

Comment: @D-side Может смысл в том что "-100"  = заплатил за коментарии со ссылками ...?

Comment: Вряд ли. В этом смысле он "заплатил" всего за один ответ.

Comment: @D-side Это была допечатка телефона, причем я ее заметил и исправил - но телефон оказался коварнее. Спасибо.

Comment: Настоящий модератор - это телефон модератора!

Answer (score 6):

Когда вопрос или ответ отмечается как спам, пользователь, написавший его, теряет сотню репутации. Уменьшение репутации приводит к активации ограничений для пользователей с низкой репутацией. полагаю, персональный спам ещё эти ограничения усиливает.

Comment: самое печальное, что помечен как спам, хотя должен был просто удалиться, т.к. просто не являлся ответом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на самом деле тут не ясно, спам или нет... Потому что это и не ответ-ссылка, т. к. идёт просто отсылка к другому ресурсу, без конкретной темы там.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а ещё кто-то в чате писал, что пытался так ограничение на число голосов обходить :(

Comment: да, непонятно. но.....написано "Удалено как спам или оскорбление 10 часов назад
участником alexander barakin, Дух сообщества♦" .... однако alexander barakin не мог пометить как спам из очереди проверок с соответствующим комментарием....так что нипанятна)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, думаю, с одним голосом это мог только модератор сделать. по идее надо 6.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Александр проголосовал за удаление и ещё пятеро отметили как спам.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, каждая отметка спама ставит -1. Но у ответа есть только +0 -1. Так что там не может быть 5 голосов за спам. Скорее всего там голос одного модератора за спам.

Comment: @Qwertiy а, ну да, похоже.