# Размещение вакансий

Tags: поддержка

Скажите, пожалуйста, можем ли мы у вас на сайте разместить открытые вакансии в нашей компании?

Если да, подскажите, пожалуйста, стоимость каждого размещения?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: @Arhad, но при этом существуют [Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) правда пока только в англоязычном варианте

Comment: @Grundy это то же самое что и не существует вообще

Comment: @Arhad ваш комментарий должен был быть ответом...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, почему? Российские вакансии там тоже есть :-)

Comment: @Grundy а стоило бы их удалить...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, почему же? :)

Comment: Эм.. Вроде ж можно было? Теоретически?

Comment: @Arhad вопросы-резюме у нас тоже не разрешены, насколько я знаю.

Answer (score 7):

> **Внимание:** я не являюсь представителем компании Stack Overflow, посему официальным мой ответ не является. Что, впрочем, не означает, что он неверен.

### В форме вопросов/ответов на "Stack Overflow на русском" — нельзя.

#### Как на любом другом Q&A-сайте Stack Exchange.

Размещённые таким образом вакансии будут немедленно засыпаны тревогами "спам" и удалены (возможно даже без участия модераторов, такие тревоги доступны всем), а разместивший их аккаунт потеряет 100 репутации за каждое удалённое по этой причине сообщение (хотя опуститься ниже 1 она не может) и будет временно заблокирован. Или вовсе заблокирован насовсем (а вот это уже хуже), если модераторы сочтут, что положительного вклада от этого участника ожидать в принципе нет смысла.

Причём блокировка будет глубже, чем просто запись в таблице пользователей — она будет пытаться выискивать новые аккаунты, регистрируемые нарушителями. Точные критерии, по понятным причинам, не раскрываются, но там, среди прочего, учитывается IP-адрес.

StackOverflow предназначен для публикации конкретных вопросов на технические темы, на которые можно дать конкретный ответ. Бывают исключения, как вопросы с меткой [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8), под которой публикуются списки тематической литературы, поддерживаемые сообществом. Но в отличие от вакансий, они являются общественно полезным материалом, могут помочь большому числу людей.

#### На "Stack Overflow" — только в разделе [*Jobs*](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab). На русском этого раздела нет.

...он изначально придуман именно для этого. [Вот страница для работодателей](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/platform/source/job-listings).

Comment: `Ты не можешь потерять 100 репутации, если её нет.`

Comment: @alexolut, должен будешь.

Comment: @Other на самом деле нет. Тут важен порядок событий, можно получить кучу минусов, но они будут проигнорированы, если репа равна единице. И последующие плюсы выведут репу в увеличение как будто минусов не было вовсе.

Comment: @alexolut А за [on hold] тоже репутацию режут?

Comment: @alexolut, так сарказм это.

Comment: @EugenEray нет. Про репу подробнее [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3663/176217).

Answer (score 7):

[Ответ @D-side](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5233/6) полностью верный. На Stack Overflow на русском разместить вакансию нельзя. Stack Overflow на английском – можно, для это есть специальный сайт подбора талантов: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent На сколько я помню, вакансии показываются довольно хитро, так что размещенная вакансия в англоязычном сообществе может отображаться, к примеру, только посетителям с IP отдельного региона. Уверен, это эквивалентно размещению вакансии в сообществе на русском языке.

Пожалуйста, помните, зачем вообще был запущен Stack Overflow  – для уменьшения вредоносного шума. Пожалуйста, не размещайте ваши вакансии (даже самые лучшие) ни в вопросе, ни в ответе, ни в комментариях. Это справедливо как для основного сайта, так и для Меты.

Comment: _**Внимание:** @NicolasChabanovsky является представителем компании Stack Overflow, посему официальным его ответ является. Что, впрочем, не означает, что он верен._ :-D

Comment: А что насчёт размещения в рекламе? Или у нас до сих пор нет рекламы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, рекламы все еще нет, и в ближайшее время, с большой вероятностью, не будет.

Answer (score 5):

#### Обходное решение

Пусть кто-нибудь из Ваших разработчиков зарегистрируется на этом сайте и добавит в описание профиля ссылку на Ваши открытые вакансии.

А для того чтобы интересуемые Вас пользователи заходили в профиль данного разработчика, он должен как-либо себя проявить: а) задавать интересные вопросы; б) давать интересные ответы.

Comment: Своеобразный обмен. Почему б и нет.

Answer (score 3):

> **Внимание:** я не являюсь представителем компании Stack Overflow, посему официальным мой ответ не является. Что, впрочем, не означает, что он неверен.

Я бы обратил внимание на 3 места:

1. В меню <kbd>Справка</kbd> последний пункт <kbd>[Бизнес](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/)</kbd>

   > Узнать больше о поиске разработчиков или рекламе на сайте
2. В [форме обратной связи](//ru.stackoverflow.com/contact):

   [image: Я хочу разместить рекламу на Stack Exchange]
3. Раздел [Jobs](//stackoverflow.com/jobs) предназначен только для этого, но он есть только на английском SO.